# Custom methods for a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, oop, methods

I'd like to write custom functions that I can call on my `pd.DataFrame` `df` using the `df.method()` notation.

For instance,

```py
def my_pd_method(df: pd.DataFrame, col: str)->pd.DataFrame:

    '''apply my_function to df[col] of df'''

    df_copy = df.copy(deep = True)
    df_copy[col] = df_copy[col].apply(lambda x: my_function(x), axis = 1)
    
   return df_copy
```

After this, I can run the command

```py
PandasObject.my_pd_method = my_pd_method
```

to define the `my_pd_method` as a pd method.

After this, `df.my_pd_method(col)` will run as expected.

Is there some way to do this in a single function that I can put it in a library, import it and start using it, without having to run `PandasObject.my_pd_method = my_pd_method`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best shot is to use inheritance i.e to create your own custom class that inherits from pandas DataFrame class.

Example:

```
class CustomDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def my_method(self, col):
        df_copy = self.copy(deep = True)
        df_copy[col] = df_copy[col].apply(lambda x: my_function(x), axis = 1)

    return df_copy
```

Then you will be able to call your method like you wanted:

```
df.my_method(col)
```

Comment: Very nice. The last line of the function `return df_copy` fell out of the code snippet.